# When making "ipa" getting error : "none of valid provisioning profile allowed the specified entitlements:com.apple.security.application-groups"

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget

I am making ipa of App having today-widget in xCode 6.1.

After successful archive when I  click on export-->> Save for adHoc deployment and getting following error :

none of valid provisioning profile allowed the specified entitlements:com.apple.security.application-groups

I check profile it contains application-groups.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: check provisioning profile and bundle id.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Checked both bundle ID of App and bundle ID in provisioning profile are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From apple docs:

"Allows access to group containers that are shared among multiple apps produced by a single development team, and allows certain additional interprocess communication between the apps

Supported in OS X v10.7.5 and in v10.8.3 and later"

So go on your target settings (by selecting the project icon in xCode project navigator) then select your target and the second tab from the left will be "Capabilities" scroll down and disable "app groups".

**UPDATE**

[Here is the apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

Comment: Can I have link for that Apple doc?

Comment: What about the custom keyboard app, where you need to keep "app groups" enabled??